# Java Pong collision detection

Tags: java, collision-detection, pong

Hello I am trying to make a pong game with java and everything works great except collision part. I firstly used Bounds class and intersects method to solve this collision problem but this method only works for the collision case shown on the picture I drew.

[image: error case]

So I wrote new code myself instead of using the Bounds class, and I successfully created method for side collision detection but I am again having hard time to solve collision detection for the top and bottom of the paddle.

```
public boolean collideRight(Ball ball){
    if(ball.getLayoutX()+ball.getRadius()>=player.getLayoutX()&&(ball.getLayoutY()+ball.getRadius()>=player.getLayoutY()&&ball.getLayoutY()-ball.getRadius()<=player.getLayoutY()+height)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and This is the method I made for top and bottom collision detection.

```
public boolean collideRightUpSide(Ball ball){
    if((ball.getLayoutX()+ball.getRadius()>=player.getLayoutX()&&ball.getLayoutX()-ball.getRadius()<=player.getLayoutX()+width)&&(ball.getLayoutY()+ball.getRadius()>=player.getLayoutY()&&ball.getLayoutY()-ball.getRadius()<=player.getLayoutY()+height)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: I really don't mean to be rude, but you should read up on game physics / collision basics. This stuff is complex and there are several approaches.

Comment: So should I just type game physics/collision basics on google? by the way thank you so much for the advice I really appreciate it. This is my first time posting question on stackoverflow and people are super supportive than I expected. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to include both the if statements in one function which looks something like this:

```
public boolean collideFunction(Ball ball){
    if(ball.getLayoutX()+ball.getRadius()>=player.getLayoutX()&&(ball.getLayoutY()+ball.getRadius()>=player.getLayoutY()&&ball.getLayoutY()-ball.getRadius()<=player.getLayoutY()+height)){
        return true;
    }
    else if((ball.getLayoutX()+ball.getRadius()>=player.getLayoutX()&&ball.getLayoutX()-ball.getRadius()<=player.getLayoutX()+width)&&(ball.getLayoutY()+ball.getRadius()>=player.getLayoutY()&&ball.getLayoutY()-ball.getRadius()<=player.getLayoutY()+height)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I Just tried your advice, and if I make side detection code to be first if statement and then make top and bottom detection code to be next else if, only first if statement works properly which is side detection code. Therefore, if I change the order of them, this time only the top and bottom detection code works. Thank you for the advice though:)

Comment: Maybe you can try and add implement both the conditions in one if statement, something like this:
`    public boolean collideFunction(Ball ball){
        boolean right = ball.getLayoutX()+ball.getRadius()>=player.getLayoutX().....;
        
        boolean sides = (ball.getLayoutX()+ball.getRadius()>=player.getLayoutX()....;
        
        if(right | sides){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }  `